# How to use Objective-C code with #define macros in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, swift

I'm trying to use a third-party Objective-C library in a Swift project of mine. I have the library successfully imported into Xcode, and I've made a `<Project>-Bridging-Header.h` file that's allowing me to use my Objective-C classes in Swift.

I seem to be running into one issue however: the Objective-C code includes a `Constants.h` file with the macro `#define AD_SIZE CGSizeMake(320, 50)`. Importing `Constants.h` into my `<Project>-Bridging-Header.h` doesn't result in a global constant `AD_SIZE` that my Swift app can use.

I did some research and saw that the Apple documentation [here under "Complex Macros"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_20) says that

> “In Swift, you can use functions and generics to achieve the same
>   results [as complex macros] without any compromises. Therefore, the
>   complex macros that are in C and Objective-C source files are not made
>   available to your Swift code.”

After reading that, I got it to work fine by specifying `let AD_SIZE = CGSizeMake(320, 50)` in Swift, but I want to maintain future compatibility with the library in the event that these values change without me knowing.

Is there an easy fix for this in Swift or my bridging header? If not, is there a way to replace the `#define AD_SIZE CGSizeMake(320, 50)` in `Constants.h` and keep things backwards-compatible with any existing Objective-C apps that use the old `AD_SIZE` macro?

Comment: Have you tried using a `static CGSize` instead of a macro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved this by replacing

`#define AD_SIZE CGSizeMake(320, 50)`

in the library's `Constants.h` with

`extern CGSize const AD_SIZE;`

and adding

`CGSize const AD_SIZE = { .width = 320.0f, .height = 50.0f };`

in the library's `Constants.m` file.

Answer (score 14):

What I did is to create a class method that returns the #define.

Example:

**.h file:**

```
#define AD_SIZE CGSizeMake(320, 50)
+ (CGSize)adSize;
```

**.m file:**

```
+ (CGSize)adSize { return AD_SIZE; }
```

**And in Swift:**

Since this is a class method you can now use it almost as you would the #define.
If you change your #define macro - it will be reflected in the new method you created
In Swift:

> let size = YourClass.adSize()

Answer (score 4):

write your constants after Class declaration. like this...

```
class ForgotPasswrdViewController: UIViewController {
let IS_IPHONE5 = fabs(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height-568) < 1;
let Tag_iamTxtf = 101
```

Comment: Oh my god. Do you think there is a phone that is 567.5 pixels high? Just write bounds.size.height == 568. And realise that your macro is badly named, since an iPod Touch or an iPhone 6/7 in zoom mode have the same height.