# How should I replace these screen size and device type macros in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Back in Objective-C, I defined the following macros in a `constants.h` file:

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
#define IS_IPAD    (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IOS7 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
#define APP_DEFAULT_FONT_FACE @"HelveticaNeue-Light"
#define APP_DEFAULT_FONT_FACE_THIN @"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight"
#define APP_VERSION @"1.2"
```

I started playing with Swift and I noticed that these things just don't work anymore.  So now how should I define these macros, and detect which family the device belongs to?

And if Swift doesn't have macros, what is the syntax of doing it?

Comment: Swift doesn't have macros!

Comment: Don't use macros, use static constants, they are much safer.

Comment: Don't use macros even in objective-c! In either language those should just be constant values or functions.

Comment: @JesseRusak macros are useful e.g. for logging. I don't want my log-statements to serve as free comments for others who RTFB (read the fine binary)... they can also be used to create new idioms. E.g. `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` is nice - and impossible in Swift... Of course, macros should be used sparingly and only when they are worth it.

Comment: Kk I get it now, thanks guys!  But what is the syntax and what should my constants.swift file be a subclass of?

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I did not mean to never use them; I meant not to use them in any of the cases above.

Comment: @JesseRusak agreed. Constants are better in this case, and they also have better performance.

Comment: @ddolce: i think you don't need a class to define constants. just write some `let` statements into a swift-file.

Comment: @Michael does that mean I'll have to define a constant every time I create a new file?  I thought creating a constants file would've been more code-efficient?

Comment: @ddolce: yes, create a constants file. Contents of the file: `let IS_IPHONE5 = (fabs(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height-568) < 1));` No need for a class though. class != file.

Comment: I think something like IS_IPHONES would have to be a function, because the screen height isn't necessarily fixed.

Comment: @Chuck oh yes, at runtime it is fixed. the executing program cannot jump from an iPhone5 to an iPhone4 at runtime...

Comment: @Chuck if you read carefully you'd see it says IS_IPHONE5(FIVE), not IS_IPHONES <- this is the generic expression that you meant...

Comment: And @Michael thanks so much for your help!  Why not just put everything you said in the answer box and Ill mark it as solved?

Comment: @ddolce: i have already put it into an answer-box, but I cannot submit the answer as long as the question is closed...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133695/how-to-use-objective-c-code-with-define-macros-in-swift?rq=1 For detecting screen size write class methods, that can be used without creating objects

Comment: @MidhunMP I'm not sure I understand that guy's solution in the question you posted...  Did he just create an Objective-C library and import it into his swift project?

Comment: Did you check that color assigning code, you can use that. Or instead of that you can create a class called `DeviceProps` and write a class method that can return the device type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, the easiest way to define these constants seems to be to use the `let` keyword. Macros are not available in Swift, so you have to use constants in this case (which may be better in terms of performance anyhow, in this case):

```
let IS_IPHONE5 = fabs(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height-568) < 1;      
let IS_IPAD = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
let IS_IOS8 = (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.floatValue >= 8)
let APP_DEFAULT_FONT_FACE_NAME = "HelveticaNeue-Light";
let APP_DEFAULT_FONT_FACE_THIN_NAME = "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight";
let APP_VERSION_STRING = "1.2";
```

for the `IS_IPHONE5` constant, I used `fabs` to avoid possible floating point rounding errors. I'm not sure if they would be an issue, but it's better to be safe...

The `IS_IOS7` macro is useless in Swift, because Swift [only supports iOS 7 and later versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001778/do-swift-based-applications-work-on-os-x-10-9-ios-7-and-lower) (`IS_IOS7` would always be `YES` in a Swift program.) I added an `IS_IOS8` constant instead...

Comment: The surrounding parentheses are not needed.

Comment: @Zaph that's true. but I like them when they are around comparisons. so I don't have to think wether it binds like `(let IS_IPAD = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM())==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;` or like `let IS_IPAD = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);` it always makes me think when I see `=` and `==` close together.

Answer (score 14):

I tend to use these three structs in every project i do:

```
struct ScreenSize {
    static let SCREEN_WIDTH         = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    static let SCREEN_HEIGHT        = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH    = max(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH    = min(ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, ScreenSize.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
}

struct DeviceType {
    static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS  = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_5          = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6          = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0
    static let IS_IPHONE_6P         = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0
    static let IS_IPAD              = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 1024.0
}

struct iOSVersion {
    static let SYS_VERSION_FLOAT = (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue
    static let iOS7 = (iOSVersion.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 8.0 && iOSVersion.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 7.0)
    static let iOS8 = (iOSVersion.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 8.0 && iOSVersion.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 9.0)
    static let iOS9 = (iOSVersion.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT >= 9.0 && iOSVersion.SYS_VERSION_FLOAT < 10.0)
}
```

And i use them in the following manner:

```
if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6 {
    //iPhone 6 specific code goes here.
}
```

Comment: I would recommend renaming Version to OSVersion or iOSVersion but having structs like this is helpful.

Comment: I don't know why but this doesn't work correctly, i.e. SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT while rotating returns incorrect values (not current width but height and vice versa). Testing in debugger with po command :) gives values that doesn't match with UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width and UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height. It seems as value isn't recalculated.

Answer (score 0):

For IPad :

```
static let IS_IPAD = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad && ScreenSize.SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH >= 1024.0
```