# How to get the device type in Swift TodayExtension

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

Is there a way to determine the device type of the device the iOS TodayExtension is running on. I am not able to do it in Swift.

I need to have something like this:

```
-(BOOL)isiPad {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

but in Swift and for a TodayExtension.

Edit:

```
let IS_IPAD = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
```

is not working in iOS TodayExtensions.

[image]

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24831850/how-should-i-replace-these-screen-size-and-device-type-macros-in-swift.

Comment: @MartinR The `UIUserInterfaceIdomPad` is not working on TodayExtensions

Answer (score 9):

In Swift you can use this code.

```
let isiPad: Bool = (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad);
```

In my opinion use this as constant.

```
if (isiPad) {
    println(isiPad)
} 
else {
    println(isiPad)
}
```

Comment: In swift 3 and above 
`UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad` becomes
`UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad`

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 4**

`UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad`

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

You can always use an extension to have direct access to your full app:

```
import UIKit

extension Bool {

    static let isiPad = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
}
```

Then, just use anywhere something like this

```
if .isiPad { your logic here }
```

Answer (score -6):

I just figured it out myself. Here is the code...

```
let iPad: [CGFloat]! = [2048, 1024]
let iPhone: [CGFloat]! = [1920, 1334, 1136]

func isIpad() -> Bool {
    if (find(iPad, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height) != nil) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: This could easily return incorrect results as new iOS models are added/changed.