# Swift - using #define in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift

I have a `Common.h` with the following defined:

```
// Get UIColor from Hex value
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
#define CellTextColor UIColorFromRGB((uint32_t) 0x217EB5)
```

I want to be able to use `CellTextColor` for the coloring in Swift. But it's not allowing me to run the macros. Only when I have `#define value @"string"` it works in Swift.

Is there something else I need to do here?

I read the below links:

[How to use Objective-C code with #define macros in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133695/how-to-use-objective-c-code-with-define-macros-in-swift)

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific answer is probably an extension on UIColor:

```
extension UIColor {

    class func fromRGB(rgb:UInt32) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }

    class var cellTextColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor.fromRGB(0x217eb5)
    }

}
```

Which allows you to use:

```
let color = UIColor.cellTextColor
```

The more generic answer is that it's all going to be very dependent on what the macro is and how it winds up being used.