# Objective-C code with #define macros in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've been using this macro in Objctive-C:

```
#define viewWidth self.view.frame.size.width
```

I am trying to figure out how I can get the closest thing possible in swift?

any idea?

thank you

Comment: Possibly a duplicate! Please see if this thread resolves your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133695/how-to-use-objective-c-code-with-define-macros-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: In the above link using objective-c code. And I am not satisfied with those answers.

Comment: Anup before duplicating please read the question properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for macros in Swift. You could try declaring an extension:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var width: CGFloat {
        return self.view.frame.size.width
    }
}
```

Then use `self.width` instead of `viewWidth`.